# delete/edit rows from odbc table

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm creating this table:

```
foreach($result as $row) {
    echo("
        <tr>
            <td>$row[KLANTNR]</td>
            <td>$row[VOORNAAM]</td>
            <td>$row[ACHTERNAAM]</td>
            <td>$row[ADRES]</td>
            <td>$row[POSTCODE]</td>
            <td>$row[WOONPLAATS]</td>
            <td>$row[PROVINCIE]</td>
            <td>$row[TELEFOON]</td>
        </tr>");
}
```

there needs to be a button/link that deletes the row the button/link is on, the same for an edit button/link (https://gyazo.com/53fb627380bcc901cf8df2f2a7d132b2)
though I have no idea how to achieve this.

does anyone have an idea?

Comment: you can create the link like that <td><a href="/delete.php?id=$row[id]"</td> and you have to write the delete.php file to delete data base on id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add edit and delete button/link in your php code like that:

```
foreach($result as $row) {
    echo("
        <tr>
            <td>$row[KLANTNR]</td>
            <td>$row[VOORNAAM]</td>
            <td>$row[ACHTERNAAM]</td>
            <td>$row[ADRES]</td>
            <td>$row[POSTCODE]</td>
            <td>$row[WOONPLAATS]</td>
            <td>$row[PROVINCIE]</td>
            <td>$row[TELEFOON]</td>
            <td><a href="edit.php?id=$row[id]">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="delete.php?id=$row[id]">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>");
}
```

You need to write php code to delete and edit.
You can get the id in your php code like that:

```
$id = $_GET['id']
```

and base on that id, you can delete and edit.

Thanks!